# Yet I am lovable

Tags: wordplay, sliding-blocks

**Transpose neighboring letters until the word LOVABLE is formed in the outermost petal of this rosette:**

[image: rosette_initial_state]

The rosette above consists of 13 petals, each containing a word.  The words spiral outward from the center.

Your objective is to transpose neighboring letters until the word LOVABLE is formed within the outermost petal.

You may transpose any pair of neighboring letters, horizontally or vertically.  No diagonals.  You may transpose letters between two words, or within the same word (e.g., CLAM becomes CALM).

You must always maintain a valid word in every petal, and the orientation of the words must spiral outward from the center.  Words should be familiar English words, not slang, obscure, archaic, or abbreviations.  No need to reach for the dictionary.

FYI, the spiral reads as follows:

```
A, AN, NO, SO, PER, TWO, PATH, SLIT, LOINS, PLIED, STAMPS, WEEDED, MOVABLE
```

For those who prefer text-only:

```
DEDEEWS
MTILSHP
OLOSOTM
VOPANAA
AIEANPT
BNRTWOS
LSPLIED
E
```

---

**Epilogue:**

Bravo to @draconiansomalian for their tenacity.

I posted an additional answer if you would like to see some alternate solutions.

Comment: Do you consider "informal" words to be slang? e.g., rot13(cb)?

Comment: Perhaps rot13(cb) falls under "obscure", I'm unsure. Knowledge of 2-letter scrabble words is more of a hinderance it seems! Further, is rot13("An", zrnavat ab) slang?

Comment: @draconiansomalian — "PO" was not in my solving dictionary and therefore not part of any of my solutions.  I tend to be much more restrictive than the Scrabble dictionaries because I want the solutions to my puzzles to be familiar and accessible to everyone.  It seems that "PO" can be a shortened form of "poor", Australian slang for a chamber pot, an abbreviation for "post office", and the obscure/archaic element of "po-faced".  All of these feel like slang, abbreviations, obscure, or archaic to me.

Comment: @draconiansomalian — BTW, just out of pure curiosity, I added "PO" to my solving dictionary.  It does shorten the solution path by 25%.  So I believe you are heading in the right direction!

Comment: @draconiansomalian — I think it is a similar story with "NA" (meaning "no").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Potential solution:**

> ```
> DEDLEWS
> LMAESSP
> OTNINTM
> VOPAAOA
> AOIEHPT
> BNTROWS
> LSPLIED
> E
> ```

**Path:**

> ```
> DEDEEWS
> MTILSHP
> OLOSOTM
> VOPANAA
> AIEANPT
> BNRTWOS
> LSPLIED
> E
> ```
>
> ```
> DEDEEWS
> MTLISHP
> OLOSOTM
> VOPANAA
> AIEANPT
> BNRTWOS
> LSPLIED
> E
> ```
>
> ```
> DEDEEWS
> MTLIHSP
> OLOSOTM
> VOPANAA
> AIEANPT
> BNRTWOS
> LSPLIED
> E
> ```
>
> ```
> DEDEEWS
> MTLIHSP
> OLOSNTM
> VOPAOAA
> AIEANPT
> BNRTWOS
> LSPLIED
> E
> ```
>
> ```
> DEDEEWS
> MTLIHSP
> OLOSNTM
> VOPAAOA
> AIEANPT
> BNRTWOS
> LSPLIED
> E
> ```
>
> ```
> DEDEEWS
> MTLIHSP
> OLONSTM
> VOPAAOA
> AIEANPT
> BNRTWOS
> LSPLIED
> E
> ```
>
> ```
> DEDEEWS
> MTLISSP
> OLONHTM
> VOPAAOA
> AIEANPT
> BNRTWOS
> LSPLIED
> E
> ```
>
> ```
> DEDEEWS
> MTLISSP
> OLONATM
> VOPAHOA
> AIEANPT
> BNRTWOS
> LSPLIED
> E
> ```
>
> ```
> DEDEEWS
> MTLISSP
> OLNOATM
> VOPAHOA
> AIEANPT
> BNRTWOS
> LSPLIED
> E
> ```
>
> ```
> DEDEEWS
> MTLISSP
> OLNAOTM
> VOPAHOA
> AIEANPT
> BNRTWOS
> LSPLIED
> E
> ```
>
> ```
> DEDEEWS
> MTLASSP
> OLNIOTM
> VOPAHOA
> AIEANPT
> BNRTWOS
> LSPLIED
> E
> ```
>
> ```
> DEDEEWS
> MTALSSP
> OLNIOTM
> VOPAHOA
> AIEANPT
> BNRTWOS
> LSPLIED
> E
> ```
>
> ```
> DEDLEWS
> MTAESSP
> OLNIOTM
> VOPAHOA
> AIEANPT
> BNRTWOS
> LSPLIED
> E
> ```
>
> ```
> DEDLEWS
> MTAESSP
> OLNIOTM
> VOPANOA
> AIEAHPT
> BNRTWOS
> LSPLIED
> E
> ```
>
> ```
> DEDLEWS
> MTAESSP
> OLNIOTM
> VOPANOA
> AIEHAPT
> BNRTWOS
> LSPLIED
> E
> ```
>
> ```
> DEDLEWS
> MTAESSP
> OLNINTM
> VOPAOOA
> AIEHAPT
> BNRTWOS
> LSPLIED
> E
> ```
>
> ```
> DEDLEWS
> MTAESSP
> OLNINTM
> VOPAAOA
> AIEHOPT
> BNRTWOS
> LSPLIED
> E
> ```
>
> ```
> DEDLEWS
> MTAESSP
> OLNINTM
> VOPAAOA
> AIEOHPT
> BNRTWOS
> LSPLIED
> E
> ```
>
> ```
> DEDLEWS
> MTAESSP
> OLNINTM
> VOPAAOA
> AIEOHPT
> BNRTOWS
> LSPLIED
> E
> ```
>
> ```
> DEDLEWS
> MTAESSP
> OLNINTM
> VOPAAOA
> AIEOHPT
> BNTROWS
> LSPLIED
> E
> ```
>
> ```
> DEDLEWS
> MTAESSP
> OLNINTM
> VOPAAOA
> AIOEHPT
> BNTROWS
> LSPLIED
> E
> ```
>
> ```
> DEDLEWS
> MTAESSP
> OLNINTM
> VOPAAOA
> AOIEHPT
> BNTROWS
> LSPLIED
> E
> ```
>
> ```
> DEDLEWS
> MLAESSP
> OTNINTM
> VOPAAOA
> AOIEHPT
> BNTROWS
> LSPLIED
> E
> ```
>
> ```
> DEDLEWS
> LMAESSP
> OTNINTM
> VOPAAOA
> AOIEHPT
> BNTROWS
> LSPLIED
> E
> ```

Comment: Of course, the validity of this solution mostly depends on rot13("B", jvgubhg na ncbfgebcur, orvat n inyvq jbeq. Boivbhfyl "N" naq "V" nera'g hc sbe qrongr, ohg "B" vf n ovg bs na vffhr).

Comment: Actually, there is a way to get around this issue - edited answer.

Comment: It's looking better!  I might be able to accept AH, HA, EH, and OH at a stretch, but I'm cringing at HO.  (Or maybe that's what Santa Claus says?)  FYI, there are solutions which use nothing more exotic than A, AN, AS, IN, NO, ON, SO.

Answer (score 0):

Two slightly different paths lead to two slightly different end states.

**Alternate solution #1:**

> 1.  SLIT ---> SILT
>   2.  PATH, SILT ---> PATS, HILT
>   3.  PATS ---> PAST
>   4.  LOINS ---> LIONS
>   5.  PLIED ---> PILED
>   6.  PER, PILED ---> PEP, RILED
>   7.  NO ---> ON
>   8.  ON, PAST ---> AN, POST
>   9.  POST, HILT ---> POSH, TILT
>   10.  AN, SO ---> AS, NO
>   11.  NO ---> ON
>   12.  PEP, LIONS ---> POP, LIENS
>   13.  LIENS ---> LINES
>   14.  TILT, LINES ---> TILL, TINES
>   15.  ON, TILL ---> IN, TOLL
>   16.  A, IN ---> I, AN
>   17.  AN, TOLL ---> ON, TALL
>   18.  POSH, TALL ---> POST, HALL
>   19.  POST, STAMPS ---> PAST, STOMPS
>   20.  PAST ---> PATS
>   21.  HALL, TINES ---> HALT, LINES
>   22.  PATS, HALT ---> PATH, SALT
>   23.  SALT ---> SLAT
>   24.  SLAT, WEEDED ---> SEAT, WELDED
>   25.  SEAT, LINES ---> SEAL, TINES
>   26.  SEAL, MOVABLE ---> SEAM, LOVABLE

**Alternate solution #2:**

> 1.  TWO ---> TOW
>   2.  PER, TOW ---> PET, ROW
>   3.  SLIT ---> SILT
>   4.  PATH, SILT ---> PATS, HILT
>   5.  PATS ---> PAST
>   6.  LOINS ---> LIONS
>   7.  NO ---> ON
>   8.  ON, PAST ---> AN, POST
>   9.  POST, HILT ---> POSH, TILT
>   10.  AN, SO ---> AS, NO
>   11.  NO ---> ON
>   12.  PET, LIONS ---> POT, LIENS
>   13.  LIENS ---> LINES
>   14.  TILT, LINES ---> TILL, TINES
>   15.  ON, TILL ---> IN, TOLL
>   16.  A, IN ---> I, AN
>   17.  AN, TOLL ---> ON, TALL
>   18.  POSH, TALL ---> POST, HALL
>   19.  POST, STAMPS ---> PAST, STOMPS
>   20.  PAST ---> PATS
>   21.  HALL, TINES ---> HALT, LINES
>   22.  PATS, HALT ---> PATH, SALT
>   23.  SALT ---> SLAT
>   24.  SLAT, WEEDED ---> SEAT, WELDED
>   25.  SEAT, LINES ---> SEAL, TINES
>   26.  SEAL, MOVABLE ---> SEAM, LOVABLE